# Spring Dependency Injection and Autowiring

Tags: spring

I am new to spring core. I am confused about the dependency injection and auto wiring.Can anyone explain

- What is DI in spring?
- Why do we need DI in spring configuration file?
- What's the difference between two by code wise?
- Can anyone provide sample code for understanding both?

  I have same questions about auto wiring as well.Please explain me about this concepts.
  Thank You.

Comment: [The Spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) explains all of this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

**Dependency injection** is a software design pattern that implements inversion of control and allows a program design to follow the dependency inversion principle(Thus the name Inversion of Control).

Its difficult to explain with some notes. Please watch the Videos of spring tutorial.
[Spring framework basics](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC97BDEFDCDD169D7)

**Why do we need DI in spring configuration file?** 
Its just a feature that we can create objects from xml files. 
It can also be done programatically.
With DI we can inject the necessary objects to the required classes. Objects will be instantiated using the bean definition in the configuration file.

Go through the video, if any explanation needed, please comment.

Comment: In that video tutorials, see the first video, then you will get a clear understanding about auto wiring and why DI is needed. Give it a try , and after watching still if u need explanations, sure i will.